# React.js - How do I uniquely identify a field within a dynamically generated component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently creating a form that has an unknown number of sensor fields within it. I've gotten the front end working beautifully. However, now I want to grab the user info out of those dynamically generated component fields and I can't figure out how. Here is where I'm generating the components:

```
{this.state.sensors.map((item, i) => (
  <UpdateSensorInfo
    key={i}
    sensorName={item.sensorName}
    sensorLowerLimit={item.sensorLowerLimit}
    sensorUpperLimit={item.sensorUpperLimit}
  />
))}
```

And here is the actual component itself:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./updateSensorInfo.css";

class UpdateSensorInfo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sensorInfoFrame">
          <div className="sensorFieldBody">
            <label className="sensorTextFieldLabel">Sensor Name:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="text"
              placeholder=""
              className="sensorTextField"
              defaultValue={this.props.sensorName}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="sensorFieldBody">
            <label className="sensorTextFieldLabel">Sensor Upper Limit:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="text"
              placeholder=""
              className="sensorTextField"
              defaultValue={this.props.sensorUpperLimit}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="sensorFieldBody">
            <label className="sensorTextFieldLabel">Sensor Lower Limit:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="text"
              placeholder=""
              className="sensorTextField"
              defaultValue={this.props.sensorLowerLimit}
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UpdateSensorInfo;
```

I would like to uniquely identify each text field within each generated component. How can I do this?

Comment: instead of using `name="text"` for all the fields, use something like `name={\`${this.props.sensorName}-textfield\`}`

Comment: @ckeeney do you know of a way that I could have these names use some kind of incremented value so that I could iterate over them in a loop?

Comment: You can loop through all `sensors ` with @ckeeney's approach. Just use `sensors.forEach()`. If you want to utilize a normal for loop: You got the index `i` in your map, so to access them later through a for loop, just name them ```name={`${i}-textfield`}```

Comment: @Tresk33 - I would be wary of using dynamic names like that. Either the names don't matter (in the case where you aren't using the names), or they do matter (in which case presumably you want to use the names to identify values, and having a dynamic name just makes that harder). What is the use case for wanting them to be dynamic?

Comment: Also, your key should not be the index. That is opening you up for other issues down the road. If your sensor name is unique, use that instead. If it isn't, you may want to consider auto-generating some id (whether that is a one-up value when you create a new sensor, or using a uuid or nanoid)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has a similar situation, I have found a solution that works. There is a way to use the key that is created for each of the components within each component. use the following as an id or name for the input element:

```
id={`${this._reactInternalFiber.key}-additionalNameHere`}
```

This uses the key and will allow you to loop over the inputs within the components.